# Evaluating a strongly typed computation graph with arbitrary number of dependencies per node

Tags: haskell, existential-type, type-families, hlist

I would like to evaluate a simple computation graph. I was able to write the code to do so for a computation graph where every non-terminal node has two dependencies (and this can be trivially extended to any fixed number of dependencies)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

module Graph where

-- Have:
data Node a =
    forall u v . CalculationNode { f :: u -> v -> a
                                 , dependencies :: (Node u, Node v) }
  | TerminalNode { value :: a }

eval :: Node a -> a
eval (CalculationNode f (d1, d2)) = f (eval d1) (eval d2)
eval (TerminalNode v) = v

three :: Node Int
three = TerminalNode 3

abcd :: Node String
abcd = TerminalNode "abcd"

seven :: Node Int
seven = CalculationNode (\ s i -> i + length s) (abcd, three)
```

The question is: how do I extend this code so that notes can take an arbitrary number of dependencies?

Something like:

```
data Node a =
    forall u_1 u_2 ... u_n . CalculationNode { f :: u_1 -> u_2 -> ... -> u_n -> a
                                             , dependencies :: (Node u_1, Node u_2, ... , Node u_n) }
  | TerminalNode { value :: a }

eval :: Node a -> a
eval = ?
```

I suspect this requires some typefamily/hlist sorcery but I don't even know where to begin. Solutions and hints welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, with a bit of 'sorcery' this generalizes quite nicely:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, ExistentialQuantification, DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, GADTs #-} 

import Data.Functor.Identity 

type family (xs :: [*]) :-> (r :: *) :: * where 
  '[] :-> r = r 
  (x ': xs) :-> r = x -> (xs :-> r)
```

This type family represents n-ary functions. The definition is quite obvious, I think.

```
infixr 5 :>
data Prod (f :: k -> *) (xs :: [k]) where 
  Nil :: Prod f '[] 
  (:>) :: f x -> Prod f xs -> Prod f (x ': xs)
```

This datatype is a vector indexed a list of types. This is less obvious. You need to store a list of type variables in `Node` somehow - but each type variable must have `Node` applied to it. This formulation makes it simple:

```
data Node a 
  = forall vs . CalculationNode (vs :-> a) (Prod Node vs)
  | TerminalNode a
```

Then a few helper functions:

```
appFn :: vs :-> a -> Prod Identity vs -> a 
appFn z Nil = z 
appFn f (x :> xs) = appFn (f $ runIdentity x) xs 

mapProd :: (forall x . f x -> g x) -> Prod f xs -> Prod g xs 
mapProd _ Nil = Nil 
mapProd f (x :> xs) = f x :> mapProd f xs
```

and your `eval` function is almost as simple as before:

```
eval :: Node a -> a 
eval (TerminalNode a) = a 
eval (CalculationNode fs as) = appFn fs $ mapProd (Identity . eval) as
```

The only thing that changes about your example is replacing tuples with `Prod` constructors:

```
seven = CalculationNode (\s i -> i + length s) (abcd :> three :> Nil)
```

Comment: In case you want a library that supports this kind of stuff:`generics-sop` provides `Prod` as `NP`, and `mapProd` as `hmap`. Also, `vinyl` provides `Prod` as `Rec`, and `mapProd` as `rmap`.

Comment: This looks great and although it will take me a while to wrap my head around it, it'll definitely get the checkmark.

@kosmikus - thanks for pointing out the libraries where I can find these things.

Is `(:->)` available in hackage as well?

Comment: @obadz I don't know of any packages that contain it, and unfortunately I haven't been able to use any of the Haskell search engines to search for a type family by kind.

Comment: @obadz I think I've implemented it a number of times under the name `Curry`, and I think I've seen it on Hackage in various heterogeneous list libraries as well, but most of those don't use the heterogeneous lists with the embedded `f` parameter that `Prod`/`NP`/`Rec` has and that turns out to be *immensely* useful in practice ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a hint from Haskell, and give everything just one dependency. Thus:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

module Graph where

data Node a
  = forall u. CalculationNode { f :: Node (u -> a)
                               , dependency :: Node u
                               }
  | TerminalNode { value :: a }

eval :: Node a -> a
eval (CalculationNode f dep) = (eval f) (eval dep)
eval (TerminalNode a) = a

three :: Node Int
three = TerminalNode 3

abcd :: Node String
abcd = TerminalNode "abcd"

seven :: Node Int
seven = CalculationNode (CalculationNode (TerminalNode (\s i -> i + length s)) abcd) three
```

No sorcery needed! You might want to make a short infix version of `CalculationNode` to make some things more readable; e.g.

```
infixl 0 $$
($$) = CalculationNode

seven' = TerminalNode (\s i -> i + length s) $$ abcd $$ three
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea and very applicative functor-like but I'd like to have these nodes mean something and not let them proliferate just because it's convenient to implement.